# How to insert duplicate values in same session for field having @Id annotation?

Tags: java, hibernate

Following is the code:

```java
@Entity
Public class StoreRunId{
    @Id
    @Column(name = 'id')
    public int id;

    @Column(name = 'name')
    public String name;

    @Column(name = 'sequence')
    public String sequence;
}
```

I need to insert duplicate IDs based on my requirement.

However, when I remove @Id then Hibernate says *"No identifier specified for entity"*.

When I keep @Id in code then the current row is overwritten with the new value and same id (and doesn't create a new entry for the same id).

Is there any way to insert duplicate IDs? (Note: column 'id' is not a primary key in SQL)

Comment: have you tried adding @Id to the primary key field instead?

Comment: I don't have any primary key in my table since it will prevent duplicates. But i need to have duplicate id

Comment: I'd definitely recommend adding a primary key field which you can then annotate with `@Id`. You can call that field whatever you want, it doesn't have to be called id

Answer (score 1):

An Entity must be identifiable by a unique key, regardless of the requirement, This doesn't need to correspond to any database primary key but there must a unique column or columns that can be used to identity an entity, so one practice could be to translate your requirement such as using `@Embeddable`

```html
@Embeddable
public class TranslatedEntity {
    private Integer id;
}

@Entity
public class StoreRunId {

    @Id
    @Column(name = 'id')
    public int id;

    @Column(name = 'name')
    public String name;

    @Column(name = 'sequence')
    public String sequence;

    @Embedded
    private TranslatedEntity pointer;

    // standard getters, setters
}
```